# {"message":"Asset does not exist"} in my css code

Tags: html, css

I have copied an HTML and CSS code from a tutorial. However, I get this error message:

```
{"message":"Asset does not exist"}
```

[This is my code](https://editor.p5js.org/MarcoGaLo/sketches/Hpm8306O5)

[The tutorial](https://codepen.io/kikopalomares/pen/zYGvzvw)

I have copied it and it looks exactly the same, I don’t see the difference

Comment: @connexo The 404 does not seem to be the fault of OP's code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it is the problem of the editor you are using. Codepen has a real URL in the preview iframe; when you navigate to a fragment URL like `#slider1`, it behaves correctly. The p5 editor's preview iframe uses a blob as its source. When you navigate to a fragment URL, it seems the iframe is reloaded, and wrongly at that.

Comment: So, how i could apply this code (or the idea of a slider) in the p5 web editor? I am trying not to use any javascript, but I would add some p5js code, so I hope I could run this in the p5 Web editor

Comment: If it isn't possible, which editor shall I use?